# How re-render component when setState with same primitive value in functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a specific case i am trying to setState and I want to re-render the component.

Below is the code:

```
const setActivePage = (page: number): void => {
    setSelectedPageNumber(page);
    // if (activePageInView === page) {
    //   setActivePageInView(page); // I want this to work
    //   return;
    // }
    setActivePageInView(page);
  };
```

I tried setting some random value and then the required value but as setState does execution asynchronously, Is there any way I can assure the second setState runs after the first.

```
const setActivePage = (page: number): void => {
    setSelectedPageNumber(page);
    if (activePageInView === page) {
       setActivePageInView(page+Math.random()); 
       return;
     }
    setTimeout(()=>setActivePageInView(page)); // this doesn't work all the time
  };
```

Any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do and what is happening instead? This sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/252139).

Comment: `setState()` has a second optional `callback` parameter which is executed after the state is updated. You can call the second setState inside it. More details: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: setState() second callback will work for class based components. Unfortunately, functional components will not accept second param